# Avoid adding same item in Observable Collection using C#

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have following things:

```
ObservableCollection<dateListModel> model = new ObservableCollection<dateListModel>();

public class dateListModel
{
    public string dateSelected { get; set; }
    public string requestFor { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string weekDay { get; set; }
}
```

Adding item to ObservableCollection using following code:

```
public void onAddClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            try
            {   
                if (model.Any (p =>string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", p.dateSelected.ToString())==string.Format ("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",myDatePicker.Date.ToString()) == false))
                {
                    model.Add (new dateListModel {
                        dateSelected = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", myDatePicker.Date),
                        requestFor = requestFor.Items [requestFor.SelectedIndex],
                        id = 1,
                        weekDay = myDatePicker.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString ()
                    });

                    listview_MenuItem.ItemsSource = model;
                } 
                else
                    DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Already Exist!", "OK"); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                DisplayAlert ("Alert",ex.ToString(),"OK");
            }
        }
```

But when I click on Add button it show "Already Exist" message even model is empty. Any how I added item in model and trying to add same item again, it allows to add in ObservableCollection. I don't want to add same date again in my Model. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!model.Any(p => p.dateSelected.Date == myDatePicker.Date))
{
    model.Add (new dateListModel { dateSelected = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", myDatePicker.Date), requestFor = requestFor.Items [requestFor.SelectedIndex], id = 1, weekDay = myDatePicker.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString()});
    listview_MenuItem.ItemsSource = model;
}
```

You don't have to convert all the dates to the same string format initially to check if a record with that date exists in the database. Also, `!Any...` is equivalent to `Any... == false`

Comment: I used : if (!model.Any(p => p.dateSelected.date == myDatePicker.Date.ToString())). Its not working. To make working above code what should be the date format of DatePicker?

Comment: The date format won't matter if you use `.Date`. Hence remove the `.ToString()` from your `myDatePicker.Date.ToString()` and try. Also I had a typo, it should be `p.dateSelected.Date` instead of `p.dateSelected.date`

Comment: Hi , Thanks. I used : if (!model.Any(p =>Convert.ToDateTime( p.dateSelected.date) == myDatePicker.Date)). Worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two dates directly without converting it to string. an additional note you need not to use `.ToString()` to get date in specific format, when you use so the Date is converted to a string and then the format will not be applied as you expected. If you go with `.ToString()` then specify format as an argument to the method(like this `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`).

In short you have to change the condition like this to make it work.

```
if (!model.Any(p =>p.dateSelected==myDatePicker.Date))
{

   // Add new object to the collection
}
else
   DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Already Exist!", "OK");
```

Comment: We can not compare Date and string(as p.dateselected is a string)